# Qt Bluetooth on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, qt, bluetooth

I tried to search for an answer for my query. It seems trivial, but I cant find an answer yet.

I am trying to run a program using Qt Bluetooth on iOS. I am able to use it successfully on MacOS.

But even the most basic feature of code like :

```
QBluetoothLocalDevice localDevice;
QString localDeviceName;

// Check if Bluetooth is available on this device
 if (localDevice.isValid()) {

// Turn Bluetooth on
localDevice.powerOn();

// Read local device name
localDeviceName = localDevice.name();

// Make it visible to others
localDevice.setHostMode(QBluetoothLocalDevice::HostDiscoverable);

// Get connected devices
QList<QBluetoothAddress> remotes;
remotes = localDevice.connectedDevices();
ui->textBrowser->setText(localDevice.name() + "\n" + localDevice.address().toString());

}
```

gives me a null vector as the address.

Is there some specific settings needed to run it in iOS. Do I need to add certain flags on info.plist file? Kindly suggest.

For information, I am using Qt 5.7 and xcode 8, programming on a macOS Sierra macbook and building it for iOS10.

Comment: Are you running on a real device or the simulator?  BLE is not supported on the simulator. You must use a real iOS device

Comment: Hi Paulw11 :  I am running on an iOS device. Not on simulator. Thanks

Comment: I don't know anything about QT, but is this code for BLE?  The sample on the QT site for BLE looks different. Legacy BT is not available to apps on iOS.

Comment: @Paulw11 : This is not for BLE.I am using the standard Bluetooth API, as mentioned in this link : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-overview.html
The above mentioned code is only supposed to provide you your Bluetooth information for the local device, i.e, the one running the application.

Comment: RIght, well that won't work on iOS.  Only BLE is available to apps on IOS

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Paulw11, indeed, it is only possible to use Bluetooth Low Energy version on iOS devices.

Although not specifically mentioned in the Qt Documentation, I would recommend you to try to program the iOS device as a BLE Central Device that communicates with a peripheral device.

Many thanks to Paulw11 for this input.